# Java boolean value not passed out of if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean, try-catch

I am fairly new to Java and cannot figure out why the value of the booleans in my if statements cannot be passed out into `System.out.println(aa + " " + bb + " " + gate);` below. The goal would be to set the values of the booleans *aa* and *bb* in the if statements, then pass both of the variables out into another method with `calculate(aa, bb);`. The proper values are returned from each if statements, but not from `System.out.println(aa + " " + bb + " " + gate);`. How can I save the values of both booleans and pass them out onto something else?

```
 JButton btnCalculate = new JButton("Calculate");
    btnCalculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        JFrame error = new JFrame();
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
         try {
            int a = Integer.parseInt(textInputA.getText());
            int b = Integer.parseInt(textInputB.getText());
            String gate = String.valueOf(comboBoxGateSelect.getSelectedItem());
            if(a == 1) {
                boolean aa = true;
                System.out.println("a is " + aa + "(1)");
            }
            if(a == 0) {
                boolean aa = false;
                System.out.println("a is " + aa + "(0)");
            }
            if(b == 1) {
                boolean bb = true;
                System.out.println("b is " + bb + "(1)");
            }
            if(b == 0) {
                boolean bb = false;
                System.out.println("b is " + bb + "(0)");
            }
            if(a > 1 || a < 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(error, "Input A must be either 1 or 0. \r\n True = 1, False = 0.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, null);
            }
            if(b > 1 || b < 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(error, "Input B must be either 1 or 0. \r\n True = 1, False = 0.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, null);
            }
            System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + gate);
            System.out.println(aa + " " + bb + " " + gate); // This one +
            calculate(aa, bb); // This one.
         } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(error, "Inputs A and B must be either 1 or 0. \r\n True = 1, False = 0.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, null);
         }      

        }
    });
    btnCalculate.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    btnCalculate.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 11));
    btnCalculate.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    btnCalculate.setBounds(72, 204, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnCalculate);
```

Comment: Declare the booleans outside of your `if` but continue to initialize them inside the `if`.

Comment: It's called *scope*. Variables only exist within the code block in which they're defined (and on lines after which they're defined).

Comment: Thank you so much guys, now I understand how it works. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variables declared inside if statements, loops, or anything with brackets {}, are *only* accessible inside those brackets. To access a variable outside of an if statement, declare it like so:

```
boolean aa;    
if(a == 1) {     
aa = true;           
   System.out.println("a is " + aa + "(1)");
}
```

Comment: You're welcome! If you want, go ahead and mark this post as "Accepted Answer" for anyone with this same question to easily find :) @Sam_C

Answer (score 0):

All variables called inside if statements, while loops, etc. are only accessible by commands inside the brackets. You must declare the variable before of the brackets, like this:

```
boolean myBool;
if (true) {
    myBool = true;
} else {
    myBool = false;
}
```

Hope this helps!